# Do the catamaran fast ferries between Dubrovnik and Split have an open-air deck?

Tags: ferries, croatia, dubrovnik, split

I’m finding various contradictory pieces of information online:

- a few recent videos which seem to show outdoor seating
- some trip reports which suggest that the catamaran only has indoor seating, while the slow ferry (which no longer operates on this route) has outdoor seating

I’m specifically interested in the **Krilo** catamaran (Krilo Star) as this seems to be the only one operating in May, but answers for other operators are welcome.

Comment: I can't answer your specific question, but I can say this: The open-sir deck on the catamaran ferries I have been on (cross-channel) can really only be used while the ship is in or close to port. On the open sea these ships reach up to 58kts. You wouldn't want to sit outside in a 60mph gale!

Answer (score 1):

Their [FAQ](https://www.krilo.hr/en/about-us/faq/) says the following:

> - Q: Are your boats air conditioned? Is it possible to stay outdoors while sailing?
> - A: All catamarans are equipped with air conditioners. Going out on deck as well as staying on it depends on the capabilities of the individual ship and weather conditions.

There's pictures of Krilo Star [showing people on the aft deck](https://www.krilo.hr/en/services/fleet/), which is the traditional place on High Speed Light Craft vessels for a sundeck. So my guess would be yes, on this particular vessel.

Comment: @Joe Malt The photos (there are others as well) do show people on the upper deck, but none of the photos show seats or people sitting down.

Comment: @DavidRecallsMonica https://www.vesselfinder.com/vessels/details/9879973 shows seats (photo #5 is even better). While most photos with people seem to show people standing rather than sitting, photo #15 in that series seems to show most people seated and a few standing.

Comment: @jcaron You're quite right — good searching! Looks like seated passengers to me as well; some of the earlier photos show vacant seats.